# applying logarithm law question

Tags: logarithms

Here is my equation (below) on which I am applying log

$X=\frac{a}{b}\left ( c-d \right )$

so far I applied it as

$\log X=\log(a)-\log(b)+\left [ \log\left ( c \right )-\log\left ( d \right ) \right ]$

Comment: $\log (c-d) \neq \log c - \log d$

Comment: There is no general rule for logarithms of sums or differences of numbers: you can only write $ \ \log ( \ a \pm b \ ) \ $ , which has no special relation to the individual logarithms of the numbers $ \ a \ $ or $ \ b \ $ .

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Thanks I just needed a confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

The equation you have given will on taking log give-

logX=log(a/b)+log(c-d)

Now as karolis commented

log(c−d)≠logc−logd
log(c+d)≠logc+logd

But log(a/b) =log(a) - log(b) 
And loga*b=log(a) +log(b)

So we get

logX=[log(a)−log(b)]*log(c-d)